# Onchange for checkbox using TreeView

Tags: c#, css, material-design, blazor-webassembly

I'm using a CSS framework for Blazor WebAssembly called Mudblazor.

I do not get OnChange to work completely for Treeview with Checkbox. The method "CheckboxClicked" wont be triggered. The code looks like this with OnChange property:

```
<MudTreeViewItem Value="@item.CategoryName"  @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(item.CategoryId, eventArgs.Value); }" />
```

But it works fine with this:

```
<input type="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { CheckboxClicked(item.CategoryId, eventArgs.Value); }" />@item.CategoryName
```

Is there any way to make it work with the code that works?

Comment: I haven't used those controls, but if the event is not firing, I'm guessing there's a custom event you need to consume instead of `@onchange`.  Try to start typing `On. . . ` or `Changed. . . ` in the `MudTreeViewItem` and see what possible event names Intellisense suggests.

Comment: After I updated Mudblazor, I was able to use a property called SelectedChanged and now it works great! Thanks for reply @Bennyboy1973 :)

Comment: Okay I see you're new.  Why don't you describe what you did, and then mark that as the answer.  That way people who look for answers to this in the future can see how you solved the problem. :D